# Show only unique URLs in delicious.com feed

Tags: rss, delicious, delicious-tags

Is it somehow possible to show only unique links in a delicious.com page (or RSS feed)?
For example many tags have the same link mentioned many times:

http://www.delicious.com/tag/cloudformation

My goal is to follow a delicious.com tag to discover links that I have not seen before.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Delicious has moved to [del.icio.us](https://del.icio.us/), I have no idea what should be the new tag url in the question. If you have any idea - please update it to match the current delicious links